# Hive action in Oozie failing intermittently - CDH 5.1 - Oozie 4.0.0

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

We had an oozie workflow with simple "create" and "alter" statements, with "create" statement using "RCFILE" file format in Hive Action.

The challenge we are facing is that this Hive action is executing successfully sometimes and failing sometimes... We weren't able to fix this.

It is throwing "NoSuchMethodError"  exception in regard to "serde".

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], main() threw exception, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoFactory.getPrimitiveTypeInfo(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/typeinfo/TypeInfo;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoFactory.getPrimitiveTypeInfo(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/typeinfo/TypeInfo;
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.registerNumericType(FunctionRegistry.java:630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.<clinit>(FunctionRegistry.java:636)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliSessionState.<init>(CliSessionState.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:623)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain.runHive(HiveMain.java:318)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain.run(HiveMain.java:279)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:38)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain.main(HiveMain.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: check if the serde jar you are using is avaialable in the ozzie sharelib path

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was in a different context, but I'm sure the underlying issue is the same. The return type of the `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoFactory.getPrimitiveTypeInfo(String)` method was narrowed down to `PrimitiveTypeInfo`in [Hive 0.13](http://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.13.1/api/serde/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/typeinfo/TypeInfoFactory.html#getPrimitiveTypeInfo(java.lang.String)) to from `TypeInfo` in [prior versions of Hive](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/typeinfo/TypeInfoFactory.html#getPrimitiveTypeInfo(java.lang.String)) which broke Java binary compatibility.

It seems that the `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry` was compiled with a pre 0.13 version of a hive-serde-x.x.x.jar, but execution classpath includes a version from newer hive-serde-0.13.x.jar.

The solution was to make sure that hive-serde-n.n.n.jar and hive-exec-n.n.n.jar (or wherever `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry` is coming from in your case) have consistent versions on the classpath.